# C# StreamWriter not closing the file after appending

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

So im using a timer which appends logs to a log file every minute. For some reason I get the error that the file is in use even tho it shouldn't. It works twice and then the third time I an error.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("logs.txt"))
{
     sw.WriteLine("My logs");
}
```

This is the timer that executes the code above

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds);
timer.Elapsed += (s,e) => { WriteToLog(); };
timer.AutoReset = true;

timer.Start();
```

The error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: opening/closing the file is slow - why not maintain the file to be open?

Comment: Probably the access happens much more often than just one minute. My bet is even concurrently, hence the exception. You could try to add a Debug.WriteLine right before the File append and display the machine clock (with microsecs resolution). That would help you to detect races.

Comment: Do you have the log file opened by some text editor while the program is running? Are there several threads/appications using this file at the same time?

Comment: The code is guaranteed to fail like this sooner or later, somebody is going to look at that log file and trip that exception.  Count yourself lucky that you got it quickly.  Open the file with FileStream, using FileShare.Read, passing the stream to the StreamWriter(Stream) constructor.  Keep the file open so it can't be stolen away, use Flush() instead.  And consider using a library like NLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of what you are kind of wanting to do.

```
void Main()
{
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds);
        timer.Elapsed += WriteToLog;
        timer.Enabled = true;
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public void WriteToLog(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var myString = "Put your logging data here: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter file = File.AppendText(@"D:\Log.txt"))
        {
            file.WriteLine(myString);
            file.Flush();
            file.Close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Do some error catching here if needed.
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following code

```
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
```

in order to write to a file that is open with another process